# MS Access, Query list doesn't refresh, GUI doesn't update

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-access, xenapp

We have some users running MS Access 2010 (don't ask me why, we have MSSQL licenses they could use) and have recently run into a problem.

Symptoms:

1. Query list does not refresh when they create a new query or table.

   - Pressing F5 refreshes the list.
2. Ribbon does not update when switching to Design Mode (correct buttons don't show up)

   - Clicking buttons on the ribbon will leave mutually exclusive buttons highlighted
   - Clicking "File" and then back to home or design page updates the ribbon
3. The main GUI doesn't update (i.e. when maximizing a subwindow, the "minimize" and "restore" buttons do not appear.

   - Clicking "File" and back to the ribbon updates the GUI.

We are running Access through VMWare hosted Citrix XenApp servers. I have been able to reproduce this behavior with my own login through XenApp, through Remote Desktop, and through vSphere console, on both XenApp servers where this app resides.

I'm not at the point, yet, where I want to reinstall Office on both servers. This problem does not appear to exhibit in other Office applications. When I run Office applications through RD or vSphere, they display the OneNote icon in the taskbar, although the correct icon is displayed in every other place the icon should show - and this *does* exhibit with other Office apps.

I'd blame it on a corrupt office/Access install, but it happens on both XenApp servers. I'd blame it on a bad database, but it happens when creating a new database. I'd blame it on XenApp, but it happens when I login via the console.

Has anyone ever encountered something like this?

:update:
It looks like, after I ran Excel to test if this problem also occurred with other Office apps, that Access is using the Excel icon in the taskbar.

Comment: I want to +1 this just for "don't ask me why"

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while since you asked, but I was having the same issue. I played around and found the line 'Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow' makes the tables I created via queries in VBA appear immediately in the table list.